# Alternative for LoadingCache (guava) in c# .Net 4

Tags: c#, java, c#-4.0, guava

Is there an alternative for Google Guava's [LoadingCache](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) in C# ?

.Net language features and external dlls will do it.

Answer (score 2):

The `MemoryCache` class is one option - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx

You can set expiration policies and memory limits, I'm not sure if it encompasses all of the features of LoadingCache but it's probably close.

Comment: Lol, 2021 year and dotnet community still don't made any cache library. Everybody relies on stock implementation with inconvenient API.

Comment: @BogdanMart yep still nothing like Guava `LoadingCache` which handles concurrent loads. What a shame.

Comment: My work around is a `ConcurrentDictionary<K, Lazy<V>>` https://stackoverflow.com/a/47489603/6122976

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the postsharp caching.

Sample [here](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/02/memoizer-attribute-using-postsharp.html).