# ConcurrentDictionary + Lazy -- would instantiation happen only once?

Tags: c#, .net-core, concurrency, lazy-loading, concurrentdictionary

#### Scenario

Let's say we have:

```
var dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Heavy>>();
```

Instantiating `Heavy` is very resource-consuming. Let's consider this code:

```
return dictionary.GetOrAdd("key", key => 
{
    return new Lazy<Heavy>(() =>
    {
        return Instantiate();
    });
}).Value;
```

The method `Instantiate()` of course returns an instance of type `Heavy`.

#### Question

For a given key, is it 100% guaranteed that the method `Instantiate()` will be invoked **at most once**?

#### Sources

Some people claim that having multiple threads, we can only create multiple instances of `Lazy<Heavy>`, which is very cheap. The actual method `Instantiate()` will be invoked at most once.

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e350f7d0-b860-482e-9b84-8dba12267d25/failure-of-lock-with-tpl?forum=parallelextensions
- http://reedcopsey.com/2011/01/16/concurrentdictionarytkeytvalue-used-with-lazyt/

I personally have an *impression* that this is false. What is the truth?

Comment: Worth adding your thoughts about _why_ you think it is false.

Comment: @Evk, I basically think that if two separate threads can instantiate `Lazy<Heavy>` **twice**, they have access to two completely different objects. So getting `Value` wil yield `Instantiate` twice, as those `Lazy<Heavy>` instances have no shared information of this method being already invoked or not.

Comment: Just add some basic logging to `Instantiate()` and you will know better than anyone whether it's called once or twice

Comment: `I basically think that if two separate threads can instantiate Lazy<Heavy> twice, they have access to two completely different objects.` Two `Lazy` will be created, but both calls to `GetOrAdd` will get the same `Lazy` object (the other one will be effectively 'lost'). So it will execute only once.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Instantiate` will indeed will execute only once. Documentation of `GetOrAdd` says:

> If you call GetOrAdd simultaneously on different threads,
>   addValueFactory may be called multiple times, but its key/value pair
>   might not be added to the dictionary for every call.

What that means is: even if `addValueFactory` is run multiple times - only one of returned values will actually be added to dictionary and returned from `GetOrAdd` call. So if two threads call `GetOrAdd` at the same time with the same key - 2 `Lazy<Heavy>` instances are created, but only 1 instance is added to dictionary and returned from *both* `GetOrAdd` calls, the other is discarded (so, even if factory has been run - it does not mean value provided by this factory is what is finally returned from `GetOrAdd`). Because you call `.Value` on the result of `GetOrAdd` - you call that always on single instance of `Lazy<Heavy>` and so `Instantiate` always runs at most once.